# Oculus Meta Developer Hub Cast Error & Unreal Engine 5 VR Preview

Tags: game-development, virtual-reality, oculus, unreal-engine5, oculusquest

I am trying to develop my own VR game and I want to see it simultaneously in oculus guest 2 device. But VR preview section does not active.

[image]

And also I have another problem from meta developer hub. I connected my device via cable. It is okay. But when I want to Cast I have a problem. When I click the "Cast" first 10 second I can see the screen of my device. But after that screen disappear and "Unable to find device network..." text coming. And the voices keep coming.

[image]

This is my device settings.
[image]

I am already in the same network. I closed my network security. And my developer settings is open. But I don't know what else to do.